# What's the 'correct' way to include unrelated entities subset in a form?

Tags: symfony

Imagine three entities - Account, Address, Purchase. Account has a OneToMany relationship with Address. A Purchase is related to an Account, but **not** with an Address - it does however have a text field for the address (this is because addresses can change, I don't want the address directly related). On the users' account page they can add addresses. Whilst logged into the site, a Purchase id is stored in the session and used to retrieve the Purchase details when required.

What I want to do on the checkout page is display a list of all the addresses a user currently has in a <select>, allow them to pick one, and update the address in the current Purchase. $account->getAddresses() exists and will show the addresses relevant to the user.

I have read http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html and http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html and can't see how to apply it to this situation, although an embedded form isn't really necessary - I don't want to change other details of the Purchase at that stage.

So my question is (at least one of): how do I pass the results of $account->getAddresses() to a form type? Or in the form type, should I use an [entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) field type, and if so, how do I get the custom query_builder to contain the current user in a form type? Or how else should I do this?

Comment: Why isn't a Purchase related to an Address? You don't want the records to be changed overtime?

Comment: Exactly, I need a record of where an order was delivered that can't be altered, so rather than storing a link to address #234, which can be edited by the customer, the address as it was at order time is stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the entity in to the Type's constructor and then use it to get the parameter.

```
Class YourType extends AbstractType
{
    private $account;

    public function __construct($account)
    {
        $this->account = $account;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $accountId = $account->getAccountId();

        $builder->add('addressId', 
                      'entity', 
                       array('class' => 'YourBundle:Address',
                             'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($accountId) {
                                                   return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                                                             ->where('a.accountId = ?1')
                                                             ->setParameter(1, $accountId)));
     }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh thanks! That's what I couldn't find documented and didn't know!